# Regular expression to leave part of the text

Tags: regex

I have a file from which i need (in any text editor) to remove all lines except those starting with certain characters: [EXA-MPLE] and remove the time.

The content of the document is:

```
[10:00:00] Hello
[10:00:01] [EXA-MPLE] Test
[10:00:02] [EXA-MPLE] 123
[10:00:03] 567
[10:00:04] Test
```

I only need to leave this in the document w/o time:

```
[EXA-MPLE] Test
[EXA-MPLE] 123
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

(?[EXA-MPLE].*)

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5FGB.png)